# How to Select or Filter out values with endsWith() in Mapping data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to filter out all values that does not end with ":Q_TT".

I have tried with the following activities

[image]

My bronze data has a column named "pnt_name". One of the rows in the table ends with ":Q_TT" so I would expect that the Exists activity would pass that row through.

Custom expression in Exists1

```
endsWith(':Q_TT', pnt_name)
```

In the future I would like the SourceData dataset to hold the filter values.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `filter` activity instead of `exists` activity for your case.

The pipeline(where you can see the 2 test cases of `A` and `B:Q_TT`:
[image]

Here is the preview of the filter activity, you should use an expression of `endsWith(pnt_name, ":Q_TT")` too. You can see `A` is removed and `B:Q_TT` is kept.
[image]